# Find a years-old comment in Facebook (given certain details)

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

So I'm trying to plan a vacation with my family, and I'm considering Belize (bear with me, I know this is not Travel.SE).

I have "On This Day" turned on in Facebook, and coincidentally, on Monday, the feature showed me a post from many years ago (i.e. Jan 18th, 20XX) where a FB friend I had at the time commented on one of my posts with some really specific and helpful advice about traveling there.

Unfortunately, I didn't take a screenshot at the time, because I was busy and figured I could come back to it later.  But it turns out, according to [Facebook's official help forums](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10101044630070393), that

> Unfortunately, **viewing your previous day's memories using On This Day in not an available feature**. We'd love to hear from you if you have any feedback on how we can improve your On This Day experience.

Is there any hacky way to add a date parameter to "On This Day" (e.g. by hidden fields in the POST)? I presume not, i.e. that FB rebuilds the OTD cache every day and blows away the previous entries, but it's worth asking.

If that's not possible, given the following information:

- It was a comment on one of my posts (on my own wall), not a post proper.
- The name of the friend who made the comment (who is no longer connected to me on FB, if that matters).
- The month and day, but not year¹, of the post.
- Certain keywords, like "Belize" and "islands".
- It appeared on my feed under "On This Day" two days ago.

What's the best way, if any, to find this comment?

¹ <sub>It was about 5 years ago, but that's not exact.</sub>

Comment: You can filter down to specific month/year in your activity log. Then it's just a question of scrolling to the right day. You'll just have to keep guessing which year is correct.

Comment: Thanks @AlE. . I didn't realize one could filter the activity log. That's definitely a good option if nothing more specific presents itself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can see your old post.

- Click on **View Activity Log** on your profile.
- Click on **Your Posts** on left hand side.
- Click on Year from right hand side (for you its 5 years ago).
- Scroll down to see the post.

It will show the all your activity in descending order. So if you know month, you can directly go to there by scrolling down.

There is a search bar in Activity log where you can search your activity. So click on **Your Posts**, and search for the word(s) you have remember in *Activity Search*. You will see the related posts.

Comment: As I mentioned, I do not know the exact year. Which means to employ this method, I'm going to have to use a good amount of trial-and-error. I don't mind that, and if nothing more efficient comes along I'll definitely do it, but I was hoping for a less haphazard method.

Comment: You said it was 5 years ago, so just guess and click on 2010 or 2011 and check. Other thing is that Activity Search, so you can use that also. Give a try.

Comment: No, what I specifically said was "*the month and day, but **not year** of the post.*" and the footnote to that criterion reads "*It was about 5 years ago, **but that's not exact.***".

Comment: In that case you can use Activity Search or scroll down Your Posts. I didn't find anyother way to search old posts or comments.